# How do I properly pass JSON array to an HTML template in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I want to certainly preface this question with "I'm a newb" I've been working with Python and Django for a short period of time now and I'm running into a problem passing JSON Arrays to my HTML Templates. The array that returns looks similar to this;

```
[
  {
    "id": "Tex"
    "color": "Purple"
   }
]
```

The actually array is much larger but this will work for my example.
Here is my Form.

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
id = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

def search(self):
    result = {}
    id = self.cleaned_data['id']
    endpoint = 'https://api.littleleague.com/players/v1/path/{ID}/playertracking'
    url = endpoint.format(ID=id)
    headers = {'Authorization': settings.E_AUTH, 'Accept': "*/*", 'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate", 'Connection': "keep-alive",}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:  # SUCCESS
        result = response.json()
        result['success'] = True
    else:
        result['success'] = False
        if response.status_code == 404:  # NOT FOUND
            result['message'] = 'No entry found for "%s"' % id
        else:
            result['message'] = 'The API is not available at the moment. Please try again later.'              
    return result
```

Here is my Views:

```
def player(request):
search_result = {}
if 'id' in request.GET:
    form = PlayerForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        search_result = form.search()
else:
    form = PlayerForm()
return render(request, 'app/player.html', {'form': form, 'search_result': search_result})
```

And here is my HTML Template:

```
    {% extends "app/layout2.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Players & Colors</h2>

<form method="get">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">search</button>
</form>

<hr>
{% if search_result.success %}
<h1>Success</h1>
{% else %}
<p><em>{{ search_result.message }}</em></p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

As you can tell I'm not even trying to pass the data yet, but still receive an error when hitting submit

"list indices must be integers or slices not str"

I believe the error is within my form @ result = response.json() I had this work in the past but the results were not an array.

Here is the Traceback:

```
    Traceback:

File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\llbb\llbbp\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\llbb\llbbp\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\llbb\llbbp\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\llbb\llbbp\app\views.py" in disclosure
  74.             search_result = form.search()

File "C:\Users\admin\source\repos\llbb\llbbp\app\forms.py" in search
  100.             result['success'] = True

Exception Type: TypeError at /player/
Exception Value: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: This happens when you do `some_list[some_string]`. The full traceback should tell you where you are doing this. Only this is valid for lists: `some_list[some_integer]`

Comment: I've added the traceback! Does this mean that result['success'] is my problem? It certainly matches your comment as some_list[some_string]

Comment: Yes. in your case, result is a list not a dict

Comment: Removing those result tags (success, message) and it is pulling the data perfectly! Thank you for that! Now I just need to rework in my error handling and I should be good to go!